# Arrested for unauthorized use of vehicle

Tags: criminal-law, theft, car

I worked at a car dealership, and borrowed a car without the companies permission, the company filed a police report the car was stolen, I get arrested and charged with unauthorized use. Today the car dealership closed it's doors and my case is still pending what will happen to the charge of unauthorized use?

Comment: It likely proceeds. The dealership closing has no relation to the case.

Comment: You probably need a **real lawyer** if you want to benefit from this. The dealership closing might make it difficult for the prosecution to present witnesses if it comes to trial. But going to trial is often more risky than accepting some sort of plea bargain. (If your legal system offers such a thing. You didn't tell where you are.)

Comment: Were you charged with grand theft auto, or "unauthorized use"?  (The latter would seem to be a violation of your terms of employment, and not a criminal matter.)  Were you caught driving it by law enforcement, or did your employer file the report after you returned it because they were upset that you "borrowed" it without permission?  What jurisdiction?  Do you have a reference to the actual law you were charged with violating?

Answer (score 5):

Nothing happens to the case. The case is prosecuted by the government, not by the car dealership. You committed the crime. The witnesses to the crime can be called even if they no longer work for the car dealership.

Comment: This is all correct, but I think that if this were my client, we'd also want to think about the likely practical consequences. Are witnesses actually going to show? Are those subpoenas going out to work or home addresses?